# CSS - add transform to element without removing the existing one

Tags: html, css, transform

So, I have a div, like this:

```
<div class="rotate-90"></div>
```

and the css:

```
.rotate-90
{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

and I want to add another class to the div, named "scale-2", like this:

```
<div class="rotate-90 scale-2"></div>

.scale-2
{
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

but when I try to combine them, the second class overrides the first one, so I get only a scaled div, and not rotated.
So, how can I combine the transforms without writing the code twice or combining the classes codes?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 16):

**Update 2022**

At the end of last year the W3C published the working draft for "[CSS Transforms Module Level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-2/)".

> This spec adds new transform functions and properties for three-dimensional transforms, and ***convenience functions for simple transforms***.

It adds "[Individual Transforms](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-2/#individual-transforms)":

- [translate](https://caniuse.com/?search=translate)
- [scale](https://caniuse.com/?search=scale)
- [rotate](https://caniuse.com/?search=rotate)

As the browser-support is over 85% it should be usable, if your project does not have to support old browsers.

So you should be able to do this from now on:

```
.rotate-90
{
    rotate: 90deg;
}

.scale-2
{
    scale: 2;
}
```

Here is a nice introduction-video:
"[A new way to do CSS transforms!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEBTTw9nwt0&ab_channel=KevinPowell)" by Kevin Powell.

---

***Original Answer:***

Transform-rules get overridden, like any other rules.

You can however combine the *transforms* in one rule:

```
.rotate-90.scale-2 {
    transform: rotate(90deg) scale(2);
}
```

If combining the two classes isn't your wish *(which I totally don't understand, but respect)*, and if your framework only has these two effects, than you could use **zoom** for the scale-rule:

```
.scale-2 {
    zoom: 2;
}
```

Comment: He / she doesn't want to combine the attributes.

Comment: @Era there is no other way of doing this. Also OP is already combining the classes: `class="rotate-90 scale-2"` – so why shouldn't he/she adapt their CSS accordingly and correctly?

Comment: @SebastianG.Marinescu, I'm working on a small css-framework, so I wanna create classes and use them when needed. I don't want my FW to override other code or other code to override my FW code. I also don't want to combine classes, I want each class to do what it should do.

Comment: @StyleShit: I understand. But you need to understand, that this is not possible in the case of the transform-property. You either use `transform` just for one effect, or you combine _all_ your transform-effects correctly for every case/combination that there might be. In the case that your framework only has these two effects, than you could try to use `zoom: 2` for your `scale-2`-class.

Comment: @StyleShit: Also you get it wrong - combining the classes to one rule is not _"overriding other code"_, but acknowledging and correcting your rules.

Comment: @StyleSh1t The specs have been updated and your wish has been fulfilled...

Answer (score -3):

Because you are using `transform` property again and its overriding previous one.

You can use both in one transform like this

```
.rotate-90.scale-2 {
    transform: rotate(90deg) scale(2);
}
```

> Transform property should be used with prefix to let it work in all browsers like this

```
.rotate-90.scale-2 {
    transform: rotate(90deg) scale(2);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(2);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(2);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(2);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(2);
}
```

Comment: He / she doesn't want to combine the attributes.

Comment: `without writing the code twice or combining the classes codes?`